# Registration of 3D surface mesh to 3D image volume

Tags: optimization, 3d, modeling

I have an accurate mesh surface model of an implant I'd like to optimally rigidly align to a computed tomography scan (scalar volume) that contains the exact same object. I've tried detecting edges in the image volume with canny filter and doing an iterative closest point alignment between the edges and the vertices of the mesh, but it's not working. I also tried voxelizing the mesh, and using image volume alignment methods (Mattes Mutual) which yields very inconsistent results.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, mesh and volume are two different data structures. You have to either convert mesh to volume or convert volume to mesh.

I would recommend doing a segmentation of volume data first, to segment out the issues you want to register. With canny filter might not be enough to segment the border clearly. I would like to recommend you with level-set method and active contour model. These two are frequently used in medical image processing. For these two topics, I would recommend professor [Chunming Li's](http://www.imagecomputing.org/~cmli/) work.

And after you do the segmentation of volume data, you might be able to reconstruct mesh model of that volume with marching cubes. The vertexes of two mesh could be registered through a simple ICP algorithm.

**However**, this is just a workaround instead of real registration, it always takes too much time to do the segmentation.